# Group a datatable by sequential values

Tags: vb.net, linq, sequential, linq-group

I have a table with 2 columns `clmAge` and `clmPrice` like

```
Age Price
1  ,  100 
2  ,  100
3  ,  150
4  ,  150
5  ,  100
6  ,  100
7  ,  100
```

Prices might be the same for different ages, and I need the min and max age that are for all consecutive ages with the same price.  I need to group my data so my results are like:

```
1-2 , 100  
3-4 , 150
5-7 , 100
```

Comment: When you say "I have a table", what do you mean?  Is it in a text file, a database, a list of tuples?  Hard to answer the question without a little more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Imports System.Data
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("clmAge", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("clmPrice", GetType(Integer))

        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {1, 100})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {2, 100})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {3, 150})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {4, 150})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {5, 100})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {6, 100})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {7, 100})

        Dim oldPrice = 0
        Dim groups As New List(Of Group)
        Dim newGroup As Group = Nothing
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable()

            If row("clmPrice") <> oldPrice Then
                newGroup = New Group()
                groups.Add(newGroup)
                newGroup.minAge = row("clmAge")
                newGroup.price = row("clmPrice")
            End If
            newGroup.maxAge = row("clmAge")
            oldPrice = row("clmPrice")
        Next row
    End Sub
End Module
Public Class Group
    Public minAge As Integer
    Public maxAge As Integer
    Public price As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: many thanks #jdweng. i was stuck to make it using linq but this is far more straight forward.